# Android listview image button

Tags: android, listview, imagebutton

First of all I'd like to thank all of you for helping me on numerous occasions before. SO have alwasy been my go-to place when faced with problems with programming.

This time however, I've been unable to find a solution to my problem...

I'm currently developing an android app that uses two activities (one main activity and a search activity). 
  Both of which hold a listview - the main activity has an already populated and fully functional listview and, the search activity has a populated one which seems to lack functionallity.

The listview is created in a custom adapter and contains an image button (toggling with a selector) and four textviews.

My problem is that when I toggle the image button in my search activity and then press back to get back to the main activity and finally go back to the search results, the image button is "unchecked". 
  Since the image button is a CRUCIAL point in both the design and the following functionallity, I'd really appriciate any kind of help.

```
    package com.example.geostocks;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import com.example.geostocks.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;

/* MainActivity.
 * Made by: Joakim Bajoul Kakaei (881129-0298)
 * Description: Creates and sets up the MainActivity programmatically. 
 *              It is mainly associated with activity_main.xml, but uses the
 *              listview_layout.xml in connection to it.
 * 
 *              The idea was to keep the class as "clean" as possible and use 
 *              multiple classes to help making coding and efficiency more easier.
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public Menu m; // Variable to store a menu-item as a public variable.
                    // This helps with data allocation; instead of declaring the
                    // searchview and searchmanager in the creation of the
                    // application,
                    // it will wait to do it once the user decides to start the
                    // search.

    // an array to store all jsonobjects in.
    private JSONArray companies;

    // an arraylist to store multiple companyobjects created later.
    private List<companiesBuilder> allCompanies = new ArrayList<companiesBuilder>();

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            /*
             * executes the AsyncTask (top10). When the task is executed, it
             * then gets the JSONArray which is bouncing around.
             */
            companies = new top10().execute("DO IT!").get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        /*
         * The following snippet mainly creates the adapterobject and associates
         * it with it's elements, context and layout.
         */

        final ListView companyList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        final companiesAdapter compAdp = new companiesAdapter(this,
                R.layout.listview_layout);

        System.out.println("after"); // debugging
        /*
         * a loop to create companyBuilder-objects from the JSONArray and then
         * add those objects to an ArrayList (allCompanies).
         */
        for (int i = 0; companies.length() > i; i++) {
            System.out.println("companies-looper"); // debugging

            System.out.println(companies.length()); // debugging
            try {
                System.out.println(companies.getJSONObject(i)); // debugging
                allCompanies.add(new companiesBuilder(companies
                        .getJSONObject(i)));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
        /*
         * this loop goes through every company that has been built and adds it
         * to the custom listview adapter.
         */

        for (companiesBuilder built : allCompanies) {
            compAdp.add(built);
        }

        companyList.setAdapter(compAdp);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        m = menu; // adds a reference to the variable m (menu).
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)); // returns the super for
                                                    // efficiency.
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.app.Activity#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.search:
            openSearch(); // when searchbutton is clicked, it will start the
                            // opensearch method.
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            // openSettings();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

    /*
     * Written by: Joakim Bajoul Kakaei Description: Invoked when user presses
     * search icon. Opens up the searchview in the menu.
     */
    public void openSearch() {
        /*
         * snippet taken from
         * http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html with some
         * changes to it.
         */
        SearchManager sm = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView sv = (SearchView) m.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        sv.setSearchableInfo(sm.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    }

    /*
     * top10 (AsyncTask) Name: Joakim Bajoul Kakaei (881129-0298) Description:
     * This class handles the connection between the JSONparser and the
     * mainActivity using a different thread. It's mainly used to help with
     * memory allocation as well as making sure the main-thread isn't too
     * overloaded with too many assignments.
     */
    private class top10 extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONArray> {
        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {
            JSONparser jparser = new JSONparser();
            companies = jparser.topCompanies();
            System.out.println("background"); // debugging
            return companies;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jarr) {
            System.out.println("onpost");

        }

    }
}
package com.example.geostocks;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class SearchActivity extends Activity {
    JSONArray companies;
    String query;
    private List<companiesBuilder> allCompanies = new ArrayList<companiesBuilder>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        handleIntent(getIntent());
        try {
            /*
             * executes the AsyncTask (top10). When the task is executed, it
             * then gets the JSONArray which is bouncing around.
             */
            companies = new searchList().execute("DO IT!").get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        /*
         * The following snippet mainly creates the adapterobject and associates
         * it with it's elements, context and layout.
         */

        final ListView companyList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_search);
        final companiesAdapter compAdp = new companiesAdapter(this,
                R.layout.listview_layout);

        System.out.println("after"); // debugging
        /*
         * a loop to create companyBuilder-objects from the JSONArray and then
         * add those objects to an ArrayList (allCompanies).
         */
        for (int i = 0; companies.length() > i; i++) {
            System.out.println("companies-looper"); // debugging

            System.out.println(companies.length()); // debugging
            try {
                System.out.println(companies.getJSONObject(i)); // debugging
                allCompanies.add(new companiesBuilder(companies
                        .getJSONObject(i)));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
        /*
         * this loop goes through every company that has been built and adds it
         * to the custom listview adapter.
         */

        for (companiesBuilder built : allCompanies) {
            compAdp.add(built);
        }
        companyList.setAdapter(compAdp);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            System.out.println(query);
            // use the query to search your data somehow
        }
    }

    private class searchList extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONArray> {

        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {
            JSONparser jparser = new JSONparser();
            companies = jparser.search(query);
            System.out.println("background"); // debugging
            return companies;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jarr) {
            System.out.println("onpost");

        }

    }

}


  Custom listviewAdapter:




   package com.example.geostocks;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

    /* companiesAdapter.
 * Made by: Joakim Bajoul Kakaei (881129-0298)
 * Description: Since the listview we have decided to use has multiple objects on each row, 
 * the listview's adapter needs to be customized to meet those requirements. 
 * This class may be revised later on (to add or remove objects from the rowItemObjects).
 */
public class companiesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<companiesBuilder> implements
        OnClickListener {
    private final int companiesBuilderResource;
    private ArrayList<companiesBuilder> companies;

    public companiesAdapter(final Context context,
            final int companiesBuilderResource) {
        super(context, 0);
        this.companiesBuilderResource = companiesBuilderResource;
        companies = new ArrayList<companiesBuilder>();
    }

    public void add(companiesBuilder row) {
        companies.add(row);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return companies.size();
    }

    @Override
    public companiesBuilder getItem(int i) {
        return companies.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView,
            final ViewGroup parent) {

        // We need to get the best view (re-used if possible) and then
        // retrieve its corresponding rowItem, to optimize lookup efficiency.
        final View view = getourView(convertView);
        final rowItem rowItem = getrowItem(view);
        // final companiesBuilder company = getItem(position);
        final companiesBuilder row = companies.get(position);
        // Setting up both the titleobject's with their corresponding variables
        // (from the row-object).
        rowItem.titleView_left.setText(row.getName());
        rowItem.titleView_right.setText(row.getPrice());

        // Setting up the subtitle's items will be a little bit tougher, since
        // it requires
        // some manipulating of the xml-data.
        rowItem.subTitleView_left.setText(row.getSymbol());

        /*
         * If-clauses to change the right subtitle's color palette to make it
         * easier for the user to distinguish increase and decrease.
         */
        if (Double.parseDouble(row.getChange()) < 0) {
            rowItem.subTitleView_right
                    .setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#E51400"));
            rowItem.subTitleView_right.setText(row.getPercent() + "%" + " "
                    + "( " + row.getChange() + ")");
        } else if (Double.parseDouble(row.getChange()) > 0) {
            rowItem.subTitleView_right
                    .setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#339933"));
            rowItem.subTitleView_right.setText(row.getPercent() + "%" + " "
                    + "( +" + row.getChange() + ")");
        } else {
            rowItem.subTitleView_right.setText(row.getPercent() + "%" + " "
                    + "(" + row.getChange() + ")");
        }
        // Setting image view is simple enough...
        rowItem.imageButton.setSelected(row.getSelected());

        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            /*
             * Add an onClickListener that is associated with view (view being
             * every row).
             */
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).setTitle(row.getName())
                        .show();
            }

        });
        rowItem.imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View button) {
                if (button.isSelected()) {
                    button.setSelected(false);
                } else {
                    button.setSelected(true);

                }
                row.setSelect(view.isSelected());
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    private View getourView(final View convertView) {
        // The ourView will be recycling / reusing the convertview if
        // possible.
        // Guess why? Exactly. CUZ WE LOOOOOOOOOOVE HAVING EFFICIENT CODE! <3
        View ourView = null;

        if (null == convertView) {
            final Context context = getContext();
            final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            ourView = inflater.inflate(companiesBuilderResource, null);
        } else {
            ourView = convertView;
        }

        return ourView;
    }

    private rowItem getrowItem(final View ourView) {
        // Recycling and reusing tags and objects is the name of the game!
        final Object tag = ourView.getTag();
        rowItem rowItem = null;

        /*
         * Sets up the listview's rowitems with their corresponding listview
         * items (textviews and images).
         */
        if (null == tag || !(tag instanceof rowItem)) {
            rowItem = new rowItem();
            rowItem.titleView_right = (TextView) ourView
                    .findViewById(R.id.title_right);
            rowItem.titleView_left = (TextView) ourView
                    .findViewById(R.id.title_left);
            rowItem.subTitleView_left = (TextView) ourView
                    .findViewById(R.id.subtitle_left);
            rowItem.subTitleView_right = (TextView) ourView
                    .findViewById(R.id.subtitle_right);
            rowItem.imageButton = (ImageButton) ourView
                    .findViewById(R.id.add_button);
            ourView.setTag(rowItem);

        } else {
            rowItem = (rowItem) tag;
        }

        return rowItem;
    }

    /*
     * since views are recycled, these references will always be there to be
     * reused. Again, it's all about optimization!
     */
    private static class rowItem {
        public TextView titleView_left;
        public TextView titleView_right;
        public TextView subTitleView_left;
        public TextView subTitleView_right;
        public ImageButton imageButton;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Selector for imagebutton

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_added_button" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_add_button" android:state_selected="false"/>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Create model for companies (ex. `Company` class).
- In `Company` class add property `isSelected`.
- Fill array of companies from your `JSONArray`. Pass this array to `ListView` adapter.
- In `rowItem.imageButton.setOnClickListener` update `rowItem` state (selected or not) in source array (array of companies, which was created from JSONArray).

**Note:** if you will save list row state, you should save this state in source array of your list adapter.

In `MainActivity`:

```
CompanyListAdapter adapter = new CompanyListAdapter(activity);
ArrayList<Company> companies = getCompaniesFromJsonArray();
for(Company company : companies){
    adapter.add(company);
}
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Company.java**

```
package com.donvigo.TestCustomActionBar;


public class Company {
private String name;
private boolean isSelected;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public boolean isSelected() {
    return isSelected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean isSelected) {
    this.isSelected = isSelected;
}
}
```

**CompanyListAdapter.java**

```
package com.donvigo.TestCustomActionBar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CompanyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<Company> companies;

public CompanyListAdapter(Activity activity){
    this.activity = activity;
    companies = new ArrayList<Company>();
}

public void add(Company company){
    companies.add(company);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return companies.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return companies.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textViewName = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        holder.rowImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowImage);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final Company row = companies.get(position);

    // refresh state of your row image
    holder.rowImage.setSelected(row.isSelected());

    holder.rowImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (view.isSelected()) {
                view.setSelected(false);
            } else {
                view.setSelected(true);
            }

            row.setSelected(view.isSelected());
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder{
    public TextView textViewName;
    public ImageView rowImage;
}
}
```

This is main idea. Also, if you will **save row states** in `ListView` **permanently** (not just 1 time when you download and show data from internet) - you have to **save you companies data in database, or in another data storage** (ex.: in text file) and next time when you open activity - restore previously saved companies list.

Comment: I added a set and get to the companybuilder (company class).

How would I go about changing and saving the state of the rowitem?

Comment: In getView method set rowItem state from companybuilder class (call getState()). In rowItem.imageButton.onClick method - change rowItem state (call setState(isSelected))

Comment: Sorry man, but none of that makes any sense for me. 
I've just started developing android apps.

Any chance you could give me a more detailed answer?

Comment: invite me to chat, and I'll try to help you

Comment: Edited my question with your samples in mind. Still can't seem to keep the image button checked when I leave and re-enter the searchactivity... -.-

Answer (score 0):

Seen your code, no where you are saving checked state of button. Point is when you navigate from MainActivity to SearchActivity your listview with custom adapter is populated and displayed, there you set some button, now once you navigate back to main activity from there you SearchAvtivity is destroyed and is completely redrawn when you navigate back. Hence you see every then fresh again.

If you want to retain checked state of button, you should save their latest state in preference and load it from there or you can keep global data variable for holding checked states of buttons so to retain it during entire life cycle of your applications.

Read about Activity life cycle and stack, when they are destroyed and created, this will throw you more insight over why this is happening.

hope it help.

Comment: Any way you could help me a little bit on the way? From what I've read about life-cycles, it's alot to cover - and to be completely honest I don't have that much time...

Edit:
How would it work if I did a new, different search? Would the image still be "checked" if I, say searched for google and then searched for apple to finally go back to google?