# Singleton variable not being updated. Always reset

Tags: android, singleton, global-variables

I posted a question yesterday regarding a problem with my listview. The state of an image button in the listview wasn't saved (it was reset to default state (unchecked)).

[Android listview image button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095610/android-listview-image-button)

However much I tried, I was unable to resolve it.

Rigt now though, I've got a problem with singletons:

I want to save a string from a row object when it's image button is "checked" and send it to a singleton `ArrayList<String>`. 
  The weird part is that the ArrayList only contains one element at the most and it even "flushes" (removes all objects) without being prompted to.

MainActivity (CONTAINS THE SINGLETON!!!)

```
    package com.example.geostocks;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import com.example.geostocks.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;

/* MainActivity.
 * Made by: Joakim Bajoul Kakaei (881129-0298)
 * Description: Creates and sets up the MainActivity programmatically. 
 *              It is mainly associated with activity_main.xml, but uses the
 *              listview_layout.xml in connection to it.
 * 
 *              The idea was to keep the class as "clean" as possible and use 
 *              multiple classes to help making coding and efficiency more easier.
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static ArrayList<String> checkedCompanies = new ArrayList<String>();
    public Menu m; // Variable to store a menu-item as a public variable.
                    // This helps with data allocation; instead of declaring the
                    // searchview and searchmanager in the creation of the
                    // application,
                    // it will wait to do it once the user decides to start the
                    // search.

    // an array to store all jsonobjects in.
    private JSONArray companies;

    // an arraylist to store multiple companyobjects created later.
    private List<companiesBuilder> allCompanies = new ArrayList<companiesBuilder>();

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            /*
             * executes the AsyncTask (top10). When the task is executed, it
             * then gets the JSONArray which is bouncing around.
             */
            companies = new top10().execute("DO IT!").get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        /*
         * The following snippet mainly creates the adapterobject and associates
         * it with it's elements, context and layout.
         */

        final ListView companyList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        final companiesAdapter compAdp = new companiesAdapter(this,
                R.layout.listview_layout);

        System.out.println("after"); // debugging
        /*
         * a loop to create companyBuilder-objects from the JSONArray and then
         * add those objects to an ArrayList (allCompanies).
         */
        for (int i = 0; companies.length() > i; i++) {
            System.out.println("companies-looper"); // debugging

            System.out.println(companies.length()); // debugging
            try {
                System.out.println(companies.getJSONObject(i)); // debugging
                allCompanies.add(new companiesBuilder(companies
                        .getJSONObject(i)));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
        /*
         * this loop goes through every company that has been built and adds it
         * to the custom listview adapter.
         */

        for (companiesBuilder built : allCompanies) {
            compAdp.add(built);
        }

        companyList.setAdapter(compAdp);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        m = menu; // adds a reference to the variable m (menu).
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)); // returns the super for
                                                    // efficiency.
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.app.Activity#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.search:
            openSearch(); // when searchbutton is clicked, it will start the
                            // opensearch method.
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            // openSettings();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

    /*
     * Written by: Joakim Bajoul Kakaei Description: Invoked when user presses
     * search icon. Opens up the searchview in the menu.
     */
    public void openSearch() {
        /*
         * snippet taken from
         * http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html with some
         * changes to it.
         */
        SearchManager sm = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView sv = (SearchView) m.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        sv.setSearchableInfo(sm.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    }

    /*
     * top10 (AsyncTask) Name: Joakim Bajoul Kakaei (881129-0298) Description:
     * This class handles the connection between the JSONparser and the
     * mainActivity using a different thread. It's mainly used to help with
     * memory allocation as well as making sure the main-thread isn't too
     * overloaded with too many assignments.
     */
    private class top10 extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONArray> {
        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {
            JSONparser jparser = new JSONparser();
            companies = jparser.topCompanies();
            System.out.println("background"); // debugging
            return companies;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jarr) {
            System.out.println("onpost");

        }

    }
}
```

SearchActivity (onBackPressed() is called here to display all elements in the singleton)

```
    package com.example.geostocks;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class SearchActivity extends Activity {
    JSONArray companies;
    String query;


    private List<companiesBuilder> allCompanies = new ArrayList<companiesBuilder>();
    companiesAdapter compAdp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        handleIntent(getIntent());
        try {
            /*
             * executes the AsyncTask (top10). When the task is executed, it
             * then gets the JSONArray which is bouncing around.
             */
            companies = new searchList().execute("DO IT!").get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        /*
         * The following snippet mainly creates the adapterobject and associates
         * it with it's elements, context and layout.
         */

        final ListView companyList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_search);
        compAdp = new companiesAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_layout);
        System.out.println("after"); // debugging
        /*
         * a loop to create companyBuilder-objects from the JSONArray and then
         * add those objects to an ArrayList (allCompanies).
         */
        for (int i = 0; companies.length() > i; i++) {
            System.out.println("companies-looper"); // debugging

            System.out.println(companies.length()); // debugging
            try {
                System.out.println(companies.getJSONObject(i)); // debugging
                allCompanies.add(new companiesBuilder(companies
                        .getJSONObject(i)));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
        /*
         * this loop goes through every company that has been built and adds it
         * to the custom listview adapter.
         */

        for (companiesBuilder built : allCompanies) {
            for (int i = 0; i < MainActivity.checkedCompanies.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("CHECKED" + MainActivity.checkedCompanies.get(i));
                if (MainActivity.checkedCompanies.get(i).equals(built.getSymbol())) {
                    built.setSelect(true);
                }
            }
            compAdp.add(built);
        }
        companyList.setAdapter(compAdp);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            System.out.println(MainActivity.checkedCompanies.size());
            System.out.println("BACK PRESSED!");
            for (int i = 0; i < MainActivity.checkedCompanies.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("CHECKED" + MainActivity.checkedCompanies.get(i));
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            System.out.println(query);
            // use the query to search your data somehow
        }
    }

    private class searchList extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONArray> {

        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {
            JSONparser jparser = new JSONparser();
            companies = jparser.search(query);
            System.out.println("background"); // debugging
            return companies;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jarr) {
            System.out.println("onpost");

        }

    }

}
```

CompaniesAdapter (Where I have a onClickListener to the ImageButton and it tries to 
                  manipulate the singleton):

```
    package com.example.geostocks;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

/* companiesAdapter.
 * Made by: Joakim Bajoul Kakaei (881129-0298)
 * Description: Since the listview we have decided to use has multiple objects on each row, 
 * the listview's adapter needs to be customized to meet those requirements. 
 * This class may be revised later on (to add or remove objects from the rowItemObjects).
 */
public class companiesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<companiesBuilder> implements
        OnClickListener {
    private final int companiesBuilderResource;
    private ArrayList<companiesBuilder> companies;
    private static ArrayList<String> checked = new ArrayList<String>();

    public companiesAdapter(final Context context,
            final int companiesBuilderResource) {
        super(context, 0);
        this.companiesBuilderResource = companiesBuilderResource;
        companies = new ArrayList<companiesBuilder>();
    }

    public void addChecked(String symbol) {
        MainActivity.checkedCompanies.add(symbol);
    }

    public void removeChecked(String symbol) {
        MainActivity.checkedCompanies.remove(symbol);
    }

    public void add(companiesBuilder row) {
        companies.add(row);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return companies.size();
    }

    @Override
    public companiesBuilder getItem(int i) {
        return companies.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView,
            final ViewGroup parent) {

        // We need to get the best view (re-used if possible) and then
        // retrieve its corresponding rowItem, to optimize lookup efficiency.
        final View view = getourView(convertView);
        final rowItem rowItem = getrowItem(view);
        // final companiesBuilder company = getItem(position);
        final companiesBuilder row = companies.get(position);
        // Setting up both the titleobject's with their corresponding variables
        // (from the row-object).
        rowItem.titleView_left.setText(row.getName());
        rowItem.titleView_right.setText(row.getPrice());

        // Setting up the subtitle's items will be a little bit tougher, since
        // it requires
        // some manipulating of the xml-data.
        rowItem.subTitleView_left.setText(row.getSymbol());

        /*
         * If-clauses to change the right subtitle's color palette to make it
         * easier for the user to distinguish increase and decrease.
         */
        if (Double.parseDouble(row.getChange()) < 0) {
            rowItem.subTitleView_right
                    .setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#E51400"));
            rowItem.subTitleView_right.setText(row.getPercent() + "%" + " "
                    + "( " + row.getChange() + ")");
        } else if (Double.parseDouble(row.getChange()) > 0) {
            rowItem.subTitleView_right
                    .setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#339933"));
            rowItem.subTitleView_right.setText(row.getPercent() + "%" + " "
                    + "( +" + row.getChange() + ")");
        } else {
            rowItem.subTitleView_right.setText(row.getPercent() + "%" + " "
                    + "(" + row.getChange() + ")");
        }
        // Setting image view is simple enough...
        for (int i = 0; checked.size() > i; i++) {
            System.out.println("CHECKED" + checked.get(i));
        }
        rowItem.imageButton.setSelected(row.getSelected());

        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            /*
             * Add an onClickListener that is associated with view (view being
             * every row).
             */
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).setTitle(row.getName())
                        .show();
            }

        });
        rowItem.imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View button) {
                if (button.isSelected()) {
                    button.setSelected(false);
                    addChecked(row.getSymbol());
                } else {
                    button.setSelected(true);
                    removeChecked(row.getSymbol());
                }
                row.setSelect(view.isSelected());
                for (int i = 0; MainActivity.checkedCompanies.size() > i; i++) {
                    System.out.println("CHECKEDLOOP"
                            + MainActivity.checkedCompanies.get(i));
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    private View getourView(final View convertView) {
        // The ourView will be recycling / reusing the convertview if
        // possible.
        // Guess why? Exactly. CUZ WE LOOOOOOOOOOVE HAVING EFFICIENT CODE! <3
        View ourView = null;

        if (null == convertView) {
            final Context context = getContext();
            final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            ourView = inflater.inflate(companiesBuilderResource, null);
        } else {
            ourView = convertView;
        }

        return ourView;
    }

    private rowItem getrowItem(final View ourView) {
        // Recycling and reusing tags and objects is the name of the game!
        final Object tag = ourView.getTag();
        rowItem rowItem = null;

        /*
         * Sets up the listview's rowitems with their corresponding listview
         * items (textviews and images).
         */
        if (null == tag || !(tag instanceof rowItem)) {
            rowItem = new rowItem();
            rowItem.titleView_right = (TextView) ourView
                    .findViewById(R.id.title_right);
            rowItem.titleView_left = (TextView) ourView
                    .findViewById(R.id.title_left);
            rowItem.subTitleView_left = (TextView) ourView
                    .findViewById(R.id.subtitle_left);
            rowItem.subTitleView_right = (TextView) ourView
                    .findViewById(R.id.subtitle_right);
            rowItem.imageButton = (ImageButton) ourView
                    .findViewById(R.id.add_button);
            ourView.setTag(rowItem);

        } else {
            rowItem = (rowItem) tag;
        }

        return rowItem;
    }

    /*
     * since views are recycled, these references will always be there to be
     * reused. Again, it's all about optimization!
     */
    private static class rowItem {
        public TextView titleView_left;
        public TextView titleView_right;
        public TextView subTitleView_left;
        public TextView subTitleView_right;
        public ImageButton imageButton;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

I've also tried using a global variable in the sense that I used a class with the application=name. 
However, I can't use that class in the adapter. This in turn makes it impossible for me to manipulate said global variables, since context is missing.

This is the global class:

```
   package com.example.geostocks;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Application;

public class checkedCompanies extends Application{
    private ArrayList<companiesBuilder> checked = new ArrayList<companiesBuilder>();

    public ArrayList<companiesBuilder> get() {
        return checked;
    }

    public void set(companiesBuilder built) {
        checked.add(built);
    }

    public void remove(companiesBuilder removeIndex){
        checked.remove(removeIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not seeing the usage of a singleton pattern there, or am i just blind?

Comment: Isn't singleton just an ordinary static variable (in this case my string arraylist) or a class that is associated with the application name in the manifest?

Comment: No it is a design pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern